# End of File in the forwarded output of cmd before the actual EOF

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, stream

I have a file with the forwarded output of a cmd command. A C program loops though the characters until it reaches the end of the file. But unfortunately there are some EOF indicators in the file before it actually ends.
The content of the file is:

```
Abbildname                PID      Sitzungsname     Sitz.-Nr.   Speichernutzung
========================= ======== ================ =========== ===============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0             8 K
System                           4 Services                   0         5ÿ744 K
smss.exe                       440 Services                   0           276 K
csrss.exe                      616 Services                   0         1ÿ924 K
wininit.exe                    720 Services                   0           944 K
services.exe                   792 Services                   0         7ÿ892 K
lsass.exe                      800 Services                   0        14ÿ300 K
svchost.exe                    924 Services                   0           420 K
fontdrvhost.exe                952 Services                   0           680 K
svchost.exe                    960 Services                   0        23ÿ880 K
WUDFHost.exe                  1012 Services                   0         7ÿ416 K
svchost.exe                    484 Services                   0        14ÿ816 K
svchost.exe                    544 Services                   0         5ÿ196 K
```

Thats how I read the content of the file:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen(completePath, "r");
char character;
while((character=getc(file))!= EOF){
    putchar(character);
}
fclose(file);
```

Any time when there is a 'ÿ' it is interpreted as EOF. How can I fix this so that I read in the whole file and stop when I reach the actual EOF?

Comment: post some code with how you're opening and reading the file.

Comment: I have added the reading method.

Comment: Both. It is there and it is what I get. I read from the file and any time I read in the ÿ (thats just displayed as ÿ in "editor") I get the numeric value fo -1. Thats End Of File. There is no logical explanation why it is there but it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EOF is not an char value. It is integer value. It is guaranteed that no other character equals to it. However, you converted the value returned by getc (which is type of int) to char before comparison (which is undefined in this case). You shall modify `char character;` to `int character;`

Comment: great answer --- much more elegant than my brutish hack :)

Comment: No, char is CHAR_BIT of binary  storage and 1==sizeof(char) as defined in C. Unsigned int is different datatype. The standard also does not define if  char is signed or unsigned by default.

Comment: @tom *no - char is 0 to 255 only!* Only for **unsigned** and 8-bit `char` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int feof ( FILE * stream );`

Check end-of-file indicator
Checks whether the end-of-File indicator associated with stream is set, returning a value different from zero if it is.

```
   while( (character=getc(file))!= EOF && !feof(file) )
```

Note:

The above code allows to use `character` to be type of `char`.

When `character` is type of `int` there is no need for `feof(file)` since the first condition would properly recognize the `EOF`.

Comment: *The above code allows to use `character` to be type of `char`* I don't think so, the `(character=getc(file) != EOF` will still be wrong, you would still read an extra nonsense-char because `feof` will return true after the next `getc` call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: @Pablo There is `&&` condition.  `&& !feof(file)` should prevent the next `getc` call.

Comment: No, read the link, or [this](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1046476070). `feof` will return `NULL` after the end-of-file indicator is set, which happens gen `getc` reads again. Because `char != EOF` will fail, you are reading one more byte than you should.